# stringReader.ReadLine() cutting off end of file

Tags: c#, asp.net, csv

I am using StringReader to read through a csv file. I noticed it was not completely reading some csvs while others would get read completely. The size of the file was not an issue. I narrowed the issue down to using

```
while(stringReader.Peek() >= 0){
    results += stringReader.ReadLine();
}
```

because when I use

```
results = stringReader.ReadToEnd();
```

I would get the entire file.

It is important for me to use some variation of the first method, because it is easier to do what I need to do with each record in the file this way.

As a note the first method is taken straight from microsoft documentation
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=net-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By `stringReader.Peak()`, I assume you were trying to type `stringReader.Peek()`?

Anyway, this method returns the next available value without consuming it. This is not anything like a reliable way to detect when you've reached the end of the file.

As you figured out, `StreamReader.ReadLine()` returns `null` when there are no more lines to read. That should be used to determine when you've reached the end.

And you can shorten your syntax to:

```
string line;
while ((line = stringReader.ReadLine()) != null)
{
    // line contains the current line here
}
```

Comment: lol Thanks for letting me know about that typo I had. Yea that is a bit cleaner

Answer (score 1):

In more modern C# you can use this variation on the answer posted by Jonathan. It uses a null-check pattern that was added in C# 8: `is { }`.

```cs
while (stringReader.ReadLine() is { } line)
{
    // line contains the current line here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somehow `stringReader.Peek() >= 0` was returning false in the middle of reading a file. So my solution to this was to modify the while loop. Here is my final working solution.

```
while(true)
{
    result = stringReader.ReadLine();
    if(results == null || results == "")
        break;
    ...
}
```

Comment: you can also use `string line; while((line=stringReader.ReadLine())!=null){/*do stuff with line*/}`